# Proper way for cancelling accept(block) and close listener in Go

Tags: go, networking, channel, blocking, goroutine

I am a student studying Go.

I am currently studying TCP communication using the Go language, but I have a question.

If you create a listener and call the Accept function, it will be in a block state until there is a target to connect.

I'm here looking for a beautiful way to stop Accept and close the listener when a shutdown signal is received.

The current method I devised is the code below.

The example was simply implemented on the server side.

```golang
func TestGracefulClose(t *testing.T) {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, cancelFunc := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        listener.Close()
    }()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            t.Error(err)
            cancelFunc()
        }

        go func(conn net.Conn) {
            defer conn.Close()

            go func() {
                <-ctx.Done()
                conn.Close()
            }()

            buf := make([]byte, 1024)
            for {
                n, err := conn.Read(buf)
                if err != nil {
                    t.Error(err)
                    cancelFunc()
                }

                t.Log(string(buf[:n]))
            }
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

To put it simply, whenever a connection socket is received as conn through listener.Accept, a goroutine that receives data through conn is created.

If the termination signal is received, the previously created goroutine closes the listener and stops Accept.

Also, since the goroutine that receives data through conn will also be blocked in Read until it receives data, conn is closed when the end signal is received.

Other than these methods, is there a way to stop and clean up a blocked goroutine for file reading?

I searched hard, but couldn't find anything satisfactory.

Thanks for reading the long question.

Comment: @CeriseLimón
I think I've asked a duplicate question.

Then, if conn or other file descriptors as well as the listener do not want further communication, should I close them? Is it correct way?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
I think I've asked a duplicate question. Sorry... and Thank you for find duplicated question!